# Comparing two clob fields

Tags: sql, plsql

can i compare two clob columns 
like comparing normal rows?

```
clob1<>clob2
```

Can i do like above?
or i've to do like this:

```
dbms_lob.compare(lob_1 => lv_old_scope,
                             lob_2 => lv_new_scope) = '-1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the equality/inequality operators in PL/SQL context to compare LOBs, but not in SQL context.

**PL/SQL**

```
DECLARE
  v_clob1 CLOB;
  v_clob2 CLOB;
BEGIN
  v_clob1 := 'TEST';
  v_clob2 := 'TEST';

  IF v_clob1 = v_clob2 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Equal.');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('NOT equal.');
  END IF;
END;
```

Output:

```
Equal.
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE clob_test (
  col1 CLOB,
  col2 CLOB
);

SELECT *
  FROM clob_test
WHERE col1 = col2;

00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 569 Column: 7
```